# Proof or Counterexample for Sequence Convergence Conjecture

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

Recently I came up with a number sequence defined as:

$$
a_{i} = \begin{cases}
N & \text{if } i = 0 \\
S(a_{i-1})  & \text{if } i > 0
\end{cases}
$$

Where:

$$
S(N) = \begin{cases}
\sum \text{Prime Factors of N} & \text{if N is composite} \\
N + P_{next} &\text{if N is prime}
\end{cases}
$$

And $P_{next}$ is defined as the next prime after N. (i.e. If N is 7, $P_{next}$ is 11)

It can be shown the sequence will loop on:
(N=5): {5, 12, 7, 18, 8, 6, 5, ...}
(N=4): {4, 4, ...}
(N=3): {3, 8, 6, 5, 12, 7, 18, 8, 6, 5, ...}
(N=2): {2, 5, 12, 7, 18, 8, 6, 5, ...}

For clarity's sake, $\sum \text{Prime Factors of N}$, refers to the summation of **ALL** prime factors with respect to their multiplicities.
For example: S(18) = 8 because 18 is composite, and its prime factors are {2,3,3}. Since 2 + 3 + 3 = 8, S(18) = 8.

For $N\geq2$ and $N\leq10,000,000$, with the exception of N = 4, all sequences converge on 5, which as shown above is a looping sequence.

My conjecture is that for all $N\geq2$, with the excepton of N = 4, the sequence will converge to 5.

Is it possible to prove this conjecture? Or conversely, disprove it through a counterexample?
As stated above, I have tested the conjecture for $2\leq N\leq 10,000,000$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One comment: you should explain that, when $N$ is composite, your $S(N)$ is the sum all prime factors, taking their multiplicities into account. 
 Some people will interpret differently and think that $S(4)=2$ and $S(18)=5$, for examples.

Comment: Good point, I have revised accordingly.

Comment: It's not clear what $a_0=n$ means. What is $n$? Also how do you get $S(18)=8$? Why wouldn't $9$ be one of the summands?

Comment: S(18) = 8 because 18 is a composite number, so the next term in the sequence is defined as the summation of all prime factors of 18, which are {2,3,3}. Since 2 + 3 + 3 = 8, S(18) = 8.

N, (The n was a typo), is simply whatever the starting term of the sequence is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is true, and it can be proven with a little number theory and some of the computation that you've already done.

The function that you use in the composite-$N$ case, the sum of all the prime divisors (with multiplicity) of $N$, is sometimes known as the *integer log* or the *potency* of $N$; you can find more about it at https://oeis.org/A001414 .  For convenience's sake, I'm going to write this as $\log_{\mathbb N}(n)$ going forwards.

We're going to need to prove a few basic properties of $\log_{\mathbb N}$:

- For all $n$, $\log_{\mathbb N}(n)\leq n$.  This can be proven by (strong) induction: if $n$ is prime, then obviously $\log_{\mathbb N}(n)=n\leq n$. Otherwise, let $p$ be the smallest prime factor of $n$; then $\frac np\geq p$, and so $\log_{\mathbb N}(n)=p+\log_{\mathbb N}(\frac np)$ $\leq p+\frac np$ (by the induction step) $\leq \frac np+\frac np$ (since $p\leq\frac np$) $=\frac2pn$ $\leq n$ (since $p\geq 2$).
- For all composite $n\gt 4$, $\log_{\mathbb N}(n)\lt n$ (i.e., the inequality is strict). The argument is similar: let $p$ be the smallest prime divisor of $n$ and note that $\log_{\mathbb N}(n)\leq p+\frac np$. But now, if $p=2$ then the right hand side is $2+\frac n2$, and $2+\frac n2\lt n$ for $n\gt 4$, so $\log_{\mathbb N}(n)\lt n$; otherwise (i.e., if $p\gt 2$) we have $\log_{\mathbb N}(n) \leq p+\frac np \leq \frac np+\frac np$ (as above) $=\frac 2pn$ $\lt n$ (since $p\gt 2$).
- Finally, one further refinement: for all composite $n\gt 45$, not of the form $n=2p$ for prime $p$, we have $\log_{\mathbb N}(n)\lt \frac25n$.  We argue as before: first, we can find a divisor $d$ of $n$ with $3\leq d\leq\frac nd$. (If $4|n$ then take $d=4$; otherwise, let $d$ be the smallest odd prime divisor of $n$.) But now, if $d=3$ then $\log_{\mathbb N}(n)\leq 3+\frac n3$ $\lt \frac n{15}+\frac n3$ (since $n\gt 45$) $=\frac25n$.  If $d=4$ then $\log_{\mathbb N}(n)\leq 4+\frac n4$ $\lt \frac3{20}n+\frac n4$ (since $n\gt 27$) $=\frac25n$.  If $d=5$ then $\log_{\mathbb N}(n)\leq 5+\frac n5$ $\lt \frac n5+\frac n5$ (since $n\gt 25$) $=\frac25n$.  And finally, if $d\gt 5$ then $\log_{\mathbb N}(n)\leq d+\frac nd\leq \frac nd+\frac nd =\frac 2dn\lt \frac25n$.

Now, we can show that for all $N\gt 45$, we'll have either $S(N)\lt N$ or $S(S(N))\lt N$.  Since this process can be repeated until we get to $N\leq 45$ and we already know that all $N\leq 45$ (except for $4$) go into the $5$-cycle, then this implies that all $N$ will fall into this cycle.  This breaks down into two cases: if $N$ is composite, then we know that $S(N)=\log_{\mathbb N}(N)\lt N$ by the second basic property of $\log_{\mathbb N}$.  Finally, we're left with the case that $N=p$, a prime.

To handle the prime case, note that by simple extensions of [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) we have that for any constant $\epsilon$ there's an $n_0$ such that for all $p\gt n_0$ the prime after $p$ will always be $\lt (1+\epsilon)p$; this means that for all sufficiently large $p$, $S(p)\lt (2+\epsilon)p$. In particular, it's known that for all $p\gt 25$, $p_{\mathrm{next}}(p)\lt (1+\frac15)p$, so $S(p)=p+p_{\mathrm{next}}(p)\lt \frac{11}{5}p$.

But $S(p)$ will always be composite (it's divisible by $2$, after all!) and it can never be of the form $2q$ for prime $q$ (can you see why?) so for all $p\gt 25$ we have $S(S(p)) \lt \frac25S(p)$ (by the third basic property of $\log_{\mathbb N}$, since $S(p)$ is large enough for that to hold) $\lt \frac25\cdot\frac{11}{5}p$ (by the extended Bertrand's postulate) $=\frac{22}{25}p\lt p$.

Now, knowing that for $N\gt 45$ we always have either $S(N)\lt N$ (if $N$ is composite) or $S(S(N))\lt N$ (if $N$ is prime), we can 'hopscotch' our way downwards to the range that your computer simulations have covered, by taking one or two steps along the path as appropriate. For instance, suppose $N=199$. Since $N$ is prime, we take a 'hop' of two steps: $S(S(199))=S(199+211)=S(410) = 2+5+41 = 48$.  Now 48 is composite, so we take a single step: $S(48) = 2+2+2+2+3=11$. And now this is inside our 'range', so we know it falls into the loop.  This same procedure will work for any $N\gt 45$, eventually carrying us to a number less than $45$ where we're assured of falling into the $5$-cycle.

Comment: Twin primes seem to be an exception to $S(S(p)) < p$. If $q$ is lower prime of twin primes then $S(2q)=2+q$. Since $2+q$ is a prime $S(S(2q))=S(2+q) \geq 8 + 2q$. Fortunately $S(S(2q)) = n < \frac{11}{5}(2+q)$. $n$ will be divisible by at least 4, so let $m$ be the greatest integer $< \frac{11}{5}(2+q) \land 4\mid m$.  So $max(S(m),  S(S(S(2q)))) <  \frac{11}{4\cdot 5}(2+q)+4$ and $S(S(S(n))) < \frac25n$

Comment: @Χpẘ But $S(2q)\lt 2q$ (since it's composite), so that's a 'single step' downwards. If you're speaking in terms of the prime $p$ itself (lower of two twin primes), then $S(p)=p+(p+2) = 2p+2$, and since this is (as you note) clearly divisible by 4, then $S(S(p))\lt p$ as I claim.

Comment: Here's an example: $S(S(202))=210 > 202$. In this case $S(S(2q)) = 2q+8$, however here's a case where the difference is 10: $S(S(142)) = 142 + 10$. And another $S(S(274))=284$. In fact I would expect to find larger differences than 10 since the average distance between primes increases as you progress in the sequence of primes. Here's one using the 999999th twin prime pair: $S(S(2*18408989)) = 18408991+ 18409033 = 2*18408989 + 46$

Comment: @Χpẘ I never claim that $S(S(n))\lt n$ for all $n$; I claim that that's true for _prime_ $n$.  If $n$ is composite then we have $S(n)\lt n$ directly. (In your case, $S(202) = 103$.)

Comment: My comment came before your latest edit. In the first two versions of your answer you don't define $p$ to be prime (whereas in the current version you do). And you claimed $S(S(p)) < p$. But that wasn't the focus of my comment. $\\$ 
The focus of my comment is that IMO one needs to show that the sequence $a_i$ decreases. So even if $S(N) < N$ one still needs to show that $S^n(N)$ decreases. I pointed out a particular case where $S^2(N)$ doesn't decreases, and suggested a remedy by showing that $S^3(N)$ does decrease even in that case. If you don't want to take my suggestion, then that's fine.

Comment: @Χpẘ But you don't need $S^n(N)\lt N$ for _all_ $n$; you just need to be able to show that for all (sufficiently large) $N$, there's _some_ $n$ with $S^n(N)\lt N$. My argument shows that we can always take one of $n=1$ or $n=2$. (And I take $p$ to be canonically prime; sorry if that wasn't clear.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60140/discussion-between-p-and-steven-stadnicki).

Comment: I agree you need to find an $n$ where $S^n(N) < N$, but for all "cases" for sufficiently large N. If you have a case where $S(N) < N$ but $S^2(N) > N$ then you haven't shown the sequence will eventually decrease. But if you show $S^3(N) < N$ for all "cases" for sufficiently large N, then there's no doubt the sequence will decrease to within the "known cases" range.

Comment: @Χpẘ That's not correct - if you know that $S(N)\lt N$ _and_ you know that for every (large enough) $M$ then either $S(M)\lt M$ or $S^2(M)\lt M$ then you can just apply the same reasoning to $S(N)$.  You're taking either one-step or two-step jumps, but you're _always_ stepping 'down', and that's the core point.

Comment: Maybe an example will help clear this up. Suppose for some $k$: $S(S(k))=k+46$. How do you show the sequence decreases starting with $k$?

Comment: @Χpẘ It _doesn't_ decrease starting with $k$; I've never claimed that. All I claim is that, by strong induction, the sequence eventually enters a cycle. Proof: Suppose we know this is the case for all $k\lt N$. Then either $S(N)\lt N$, in which case we can apply the 'inductive' step: since $S(N)$ eventually enters a cycle then we know that $N$ enters the same cycle (with one additional step) - or $S(S(N))\lt N$, in which case we apply the inductive step to $S(S(N))$; since $S(S(N))$ eventually enters a cycle, then $N$ enters the same cycle (with two additional steps).

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. In the particular case above, you would say that $m=S(k) < k$ and then in the next step you'd say $S(S(m))<m$. In effect you wouldn't have to worry about the fact that $S(S(k)) = k + 46$. Whereas I was saying you could take care of this value of $k$ by saying $S^3(k)<k$, which is somewhat less elegant, if the proof has to mention all 3 of: $S(N), S^2(N), S^3(N)$. But you could prove with just one case: $S^3(N) < N$, albeit the algebra becomes more complex.

Comment: @Χpẘ It's not always the case that $S^3(N)\lt N$ if $N$ is prime, though: consider $N=971$. Then $p_{\mathrm next}=977$, and $S(N)=971+977=2^2\cdot487$. So $S(S(N))=2+2+487=491$, which is also prime, (with $p_{\mathrm next}(491)=499$), and $S(S(S(N))) = 990$!

Comment: (This doesn't contradict the theorem because $S^4(N)\lt S^2(N)\lt N$ - but it shows that it's really hard to be able to choose a _fixed_ $k$ such that $S^k(N)\lt N$ for all $N$; it's why I used two different $k$ in my proof.)

Comment: Interesting and surprising. I wonder if there's a small $n$ such that $S^n(N) < N$ for all $N$.